# TableLayoutPanel fill top-to-bottom instead of left-to-right?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Is it possible to have a `System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel` fill a column before moving to the next one? Regardless of how I set the `RowCount`, `ColumnCount`, and `GrowStyle`, the table is always populated like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and I want this:

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

Can a TableLayoutPanel not automatically do this?

Edit - To clarify, I am adding the controls programmatically.

Comment: Do you mean when adding controls programmatically to a TLP of sufficient size?

Comment: @GertArnold: Yes, of sufficient size (when trying `GrowStyle.FizedSize`). I just want to say `Controls.Add(...)` and have the table fill as described above.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much you can do about it. It's just how [`TableLayoutControlCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add.aspx) is implemented internally. I see two options:

- Use [TableLayoutControlCollection.Add(Control, column, row)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a.aspx). But that's quite a hassle, because you need to calculate the column/row values each time you add a control.
- Create a derived control that overrides `Add` and implement it as the overload above - but now internally.